# Yelp dataset's json_to_csv_converter.py file error

Tags: python, json, csv

I had read Yelp dataset's documentation well, proceeded to download the yelp_dataset.tar and extracted all json files (without any character encoding error). Unfortunately, converting those files from [json](/questions/tagged/json) to [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) would output this:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplejson'`

[You can have a look at the json_to_csv_converter.py file's image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cccvl.png)

Can someone help solve this problem?
Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: [Please post your code and error traceback message as text, not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/).

Answer (score 2):

You can install the `simplejson` using pip if it's not installed. If it's still causing the issues, you can use `json` form python built-in libraries.

`json` is `simplejson`, added to the stdlib. Json library is as fast as simplejson and has fewer refused-to-be-fixed [Unicode bugs](https://code.google.com/archive/p/simplejson/issues/40).

A good practice will be to use one or the other as a fallback.

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

Answer (score 0):

[simplejson](https://pypi.org/project/simplejson/) is not part of the standard library and needs to be installed. Have you tried installing it?

`pip install simplejson`
will work if you use pip, or
`conda install simplejson` for conda